# upload files in Godaddy cpanel, then create download link in WordPress. Possible?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I want to upload some video files in a GoDaddy cpanel folder, then create a downloadable link in a webpage and source it to that folder. I am assuming WordPress does not communicate with other folders in cpanel.

I am also getting this error
Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page.

my
Maximum upload file size: 1 GB. I changed the configuration.

GoDaddy Rep suggested to optimize files and upload it inside WP.

Answer (score 0):

Found it LOL

You can link to a file on your host (in my case GoDaddy).

The file path will be:
http://www.YourSiteName.com/TheFolderName/FileName

Then you just create the link and use that path in WordPress web page Download Link.

The other upload issue is being fixed by GoDaddy engineers. Cheers

Comment: We're experiencing the same problem as your original post above. 
Did the GoDaddy engineers get back to you with a resolution?

Comment: I haven't bothered with it since I don't need to upload it directly in WordPress anymore. They haven't though